# Use await in javascript conditional loop gives error

Tags: javascript

I am new to javascript and need to implement a script that calls my backend a total of 60 sec duration with 1 sec interval between the calls. The backend can respond with either `true`, `false` and `'Try again'`. If the response is `true` I will redirect user to one location, if respond is `false` I will redirect user to another location. If response is `'Try again'` I will stay in the loop until passing 60 sec. Below is the partial implemented code and I get an error in `let paymentResponse = await verifyPayment();`
Uncaught SyntaxError: await is only valid in async functions and the top level bodies of modules. Is it possible to accomplish what I want without using `paymentResponse.then`?

```
async function verifyPayment() {
    const result = await $.ajax({
            url : "backendPaymentVerification",
            type : "get",
            data : {},
    })
    return result;
}

function countDownBackForRedirect() {
    console.log('count down called')
    for (let i = 5; i > 0; i--) {
        window.setTimeout(function() {
            console.log(i);
            document.getElementById('paymentVerificationText').innerHTML = 'Payment failed. Redirecting you to payment again in... ' + i + ' sec';  
        }, 1000)
    }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    //Do a loop with 1 sec sleep for 1 minutes. In each loop iteration check for payment received
    var timeCountDownSec = 60;
    var timeLoop = setInterval(function() {

        //Must await for payment response before proceeding
        let paymentResponse = await verifyPayment();

        //I wish something like

        if (paymentResponse == false) {
            clearInterva(timeLoop)
            countDownBackForRedirect()
            window.location = "/somewhere"   
        }
        }, 1000)
})
```

Comment: Make the callback function `async`?

Comment: do you mean? let paymentResponse = async verifyPayment();?

Comment: `setInterval(function() {` ---> `setInterval(async function() {`

Comment: Thanks it solved the issue. Am I correct that if await is called inside a block, then the block itself must be async before it works?

Comment: @jxw the function must be async. Anything inside that function can then be `await`ed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to adopt a slightly different approach using `setTimeout`, but the bones of using a `promise` in your `countDownBackForRedirect` so that the main function has to wait until that process is complete before it redirects to a new page, and using `switch` in the main function to redirect on `true`/`false`, or just keep looping until the 60 seconds are there.

```js
// No need for this to be async - just
// return the promise
function verifyPayment() {
  return $.ajax({
    url: "backendPaymentVerification",
    type: "get",
    data: {},
  })
}

function countDownBackForRedirect(value) {

  // Create a new promise the response from which
  // we return when `count` reaches zero
  return new Promise((res, rej) => {

    // Cache the element
    const div = document.getElementById('paymentVerificationText');

    // Count is initially 5
    function loop(count = 5) {

      // If count is 0 return the promise response
      if (!count) res();

      let text;

      // Change the text based on the value passed
      // into the function
      if (!value) {
        text = `Payment failed.`
      } else {
        text = `Payment succeeded.`
      }

      // Otherwise update the text content of the div
      div.textContent = `${text} Redirecting you in ${count} seconds`;

      // And call the loop function again reducing
      // the count variable by 1
      setTimeout(loop, 1000, --count);
    }

    loop();
  
  });

}

$(document).ready(function() {

  // Initialise timeCountDownSec to 60
  function checkPayment(timeCountDownSec = 60) {

    async function loop() {

      let paymentResponse = await verifyPayment();

      // Redirect on true/false
      // Pass an argument into the function 
      // so it knows what text to add to the div
      switch (paymentResponse) {

        case false:
          await countDownBackForRedirect(false);
          window.location.href = '/here';
          break;

        case true:
          await countDownBackForRedirect(true);
          window.location.href = '/somewhere';
          break;

        default: {

          // And if timeCountDownSec is greater than 0
          // call the loop again to make another API call
          if (timeCountDownSec > 0) {
            setTimeout(loop, 1000, --timeCountDownSec);
          }

        }

      }

    }
    
    loop();
    
  }

});
```

--

Comment: This one really worked. Thanks so much. I think coding it with switch makes the code simpler and more readable.

Comment: FWIW using `setTimeout` in a loop rather than `setInterval` is a personal choice. It doesn't suit everyone, but it's more intuitive for me.

Answer (score 2):

You need to define the `setInterval callback` function to be `async`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //Do a loop with 1 sec sleep for 1 minutes. In each loop iteration check for payment received
    var timeCountDownSec = 60;
    var timeLoop = setInterval(async function() { // async here

        //Must await for payment response before proceeding
        let paymentResponse = await verifyPayment();

        //I wish something like

        if (paymentResponse == false) {
            clearInterva(timeLoop)
            countDownBackForRedirect()
            window.location = "/somewhere"   
        }
        }, 1000)
})
```